# cacheLength option for autocomplete - jQuery 1.4.2 and 1.8 (UI)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using autocomplete with a remote server. The following code works for me, but I did not understand the options delay, enable, and cacheLength. Especially I need to know what `cacheLenght` is, and how can I verify if the results are being cached. I am using the following libraries:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />
  <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>

$("#boxId").autocomplete({
  source:<url>,
  minLength:4,
  delay:1000,
  enable:true,
  cacheLength:1
});
```

I need to use the cache as i don't want to send repeated requests.

Comment: I looked in the doc for the actual version (1.8.21) of the plugin and couldn't find the mentionded options (except of delay). http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/ Do you have a modified version of the plugin?

Comment: Could you tell me which version should i use so that i can use a cache option ?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Was on vacation. No, i don't know a version with build in caching. Maybe the plugin is mentioned in the article where you found the options or you can place a question there. If not, you could write a cache yourself. If there is a stable autocomplete plugin with caching out there, please give me a link.